# Is there a version of the 'Hunters' map from Brood War for StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In StarCraft: Brood War, we had the 'Hunters' map.  Does it exist in StarCraft 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Starcraft it was known as "Hunters," but in Broodwars it was called "Big Game Hunters" or BGH.

It does exist as a [custom map](http://starcraft.incgamers.com/maps/?p=mod&m=69)

Comment: Don't they (Blizzard) include it into ladder maps?

Comment: @Budda not in SC2, no

Comment: What's a pity... I like it

Comment: Big game hunters was the hunters map with much more resources at each expo.